# Function for pivot tables and merge in R

Tags: r

I need a help in an easy task, I believe. I am not so used to functions in R.
I have two data frames (df1 and df2) and I would like to:

1) filter df1 by a column value (output = A);

2) generate a pivot table from A (output = B);

3) rename B's columns;

4) merge this pivot table B with the second data frame df2 (output = C);

5) divide the values of a column from df2 by the values of a column from C.

I want to perform this task 13 times, that's why I would like to do a `function` / `loop` / use `lapply` or any other way that would make my life easier.

As I see, in R usually it is better to use lapply. Intuitively, I would use some kind of a function or loop for this task.

Check below a reproducible example for two variables (MLB and D).

```
library(dplyr)
df<-   as.data.frame(cbind(c("NC_1","NC_1","NC_2","NC_2","NC_2","NC_1","NC_1","NC_1","NC_2","NC_1"),
              c("MLB","MLB","MLB","MLB","MLB","MLB","D","D","D","D"),
                 c("ATT","ATT","ATT","ATT1","ATT1","ATT1","ATT1","ATT1","ATT1","ATT1")))

names(df) <- c("TAG", "ST", "ATR")
general.table<-table(df$TAG)
general.table<-as.data.frame(general.table)
names(general.table) <- c("TAG", "OCC")

# MLB

MLB.df<-filter(df, grepl('MLB', ST)) # 1) Filter 
MLB.df.table<-as.data.frame(table(MLB.df$TAG)) # 2) Pivot Table
names(MLB.df.table)<-c("TAG", "Partial_Score") # 3) Rename 
MLB.df.final.table<-merge(general.table,MLB.df.table,by='TAG', all.x=T) # 4) Merge
MLB.df.final.table$Partial_Score<-MLB.df.final.table$Partial_Score / general.table$OCC # 5) Divide one column by other

# D - The same tasks to be performed just like MLB
D.df<-filter(df, grepl('D', ST))
D.df.table<-as.data.frame(table(D.df$TAG))
names(D.df.table)<-c("TAG", "Partial_Score")
D.df.final.table<-merge(general.table,D.df.table,by='TAG', all.x=T)
D.df.final.table$Partial_Score<-D.df.final.table$Partial_Score / general.table$OCC
```

I also wonder if there is a way to performe those 5 tasks by only changing the strings. For instance, the only difference between the tasks 1) to 5) performed for `MLB` and `D` was only the strings "MLB" and "D". I tried to create a vector with this MLB, D and the other 11 strings and then use `assign` and `paste` functions, without success.

So, in short, what I would like is to have a solution using:

A) Function / loop;

B) lapply;

C) If it is possible, perform the tasks by only varying the strings `MLB` and `D`.

Of course, one solution is enough for me. The others are just to didactically better understand R.

Thank you very much in advance. Please let me know if you guys need any more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the intermediate solutions, only the ...final.table ones, I would suggest the following function:

```
calc.partial.score <- function(df, general.table, filter.expr) {
  df %>% 
    filter(grepl(filter.expr, ST)) %>%
    count(TAG) %>%
    merge(general.table, by = 'TAG', all.x = T) %>%
    mutate(Partial_Score = n / OCC) %>%
    select(-n)
}
```

Use it the following way:

```
> calc.partial.score(df, general.table, "MLB")
   TAG OCC Partial_Score
1 NC_1   6          0.50
2 NC_2   4          0.75

> calc.partial.score(df, general.table, "D")
   TAG OCC Partial_Score
1 NC_1   6          0.50
2 NC_2   4          0.25
```